# How to discover user doesn't operate the Swing app for some time

Tags: java, swing

We have a Swing application, currently I need to add a feature that is to do some jobs when user doesn't operate the application for some time (e.g. 5 minutes). I have no idea how to implement this (maybe should monitor all the action events invoked by user, if for 5 minutes no new action even is raised do the jobs, but don't know how). Any suggestions will be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a system-wide [AWTEventListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/AWTEventListener.html) in order to receive all AWTEvents that you are interested in.

For example, the following code will tell you whenever the mouse enters, exits or is clicked within your swing application. It will also tell you whenever the user types any key within your application. Based on this information, you can start a timer in order to keep track of user "idle" time.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }
}, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

Take a look a the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html) for the full list of event masks you can listen to.

Answer (score 4):

yes sure this/there feature(s) exists, [here are excelent workaround](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=inactivity%20listener) by @camickr

Comment: My comments to the effect 'the SSCCE is disappearing' were premature.  It has now found a new home at Java Ranch.  It is also significantly smaller (50% less download/40% less page downs).

Comment: yes very good forum, there is a few very common users, I'm active on coderanch and daniweb, and monitoring oracles OTN

Comment: *"..oracles OTN"*  I gave up on that as soon as I got settled in at SO.  I occasionally give Java/code ranch a look in.

Comment: both coderanch and javaranch loves an SSCCE, I'm still hope that you don't want to cut off this domain from net

Comment: No worries with that.  Java Ranch also took over the domain (which I never owned, but put them onto the domain holder), and I am guessing, will maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with "monitoring" the actions as you though as well.

The best approach would be to derive all your actions from one base class that in turn calls some kind of "Heartbeat Manager" each time the action is invoked.

The "Heartbeat Manager" records the last time the userDidSomething() method was called and checks in a background Timer if 5 minutes have elapsed since the last recorded timestamp. If yes, it starts the job (in a separate thread)